Upserting Data into Pinecone Using .NET and Reading It with Flowise
I want to upsert data into Pinecone using .NET (not using the upsert feature in Flowise). After that, I want to connect to Pinecone with a connection key and read the dataset using Flowise. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?
Additionally, my dataset doesn't contains the following metadata fields: blobType, line, loc.lines.from, loc.lines.to, and source. Are these fields mandatory for this process?"
i want connect with flowise and get answer about dataset
